# Angular Material Sublime text 3 indentation

Tags: angularjs, sublimetext3, angular-material

I've tried auto re-indenting my angularJS + Angular material + html code, but the default indentation is ridiculous,it looks like so:

```
<md-menu-item layout="column">
<md-button ng-href="/profile" href="/profile" flex layout="row" layout-       align="center center">
<md-icon md-font-set="material-icons">account_circle</md-icon>
<span>Profile</span>
</md-button>
</md-menu-item>
```

So basically it's NON-EXISTENT . It's really annoying and I'd hate to have to indent manually all of my code.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try out Visual Studio after installing Nuget package for AngularJS. It provides you full intelli-sense and code indentation you are looking for. 
What more? There is now a free version also of Visual Studio.